# SQL update statement in Flask

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

This piece of code is not working and I have not been able to figure out why:

```
db = get_db()
done = "1"
db.execute(
   'UPDATE post'
   'SET payment = (?)'
   'WHERE unique_id = (?)',
   (done, unique_id)
)
db.commit()
```

It gives me this error:

> File "/mnt/c/Users/Uvo/Desktop/JobApp/main_page.py", line 163, in
> stripe_webhook
> (done, unique_id)
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "payment": syntax error

I tried a lot of different things without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a simple solution by myself : writing the SQL query on the same line.

```
db = get_db()
db.execute('UPDATE post SET payment = "1" WHERE unique_id = (?)',
(unique_id,)
)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLAlchemy this should work:

```
db = get_db()
done = "1"
db.execute(
   'UPDATE post '
   'SET payment =:payment '
   'WHERE unique_id =:unique_id',
   payment=done, unique_id=12345)
)
db.commit()
```

Note the payment column will have an entry '1'. If this should be the ID, please change the 12345 correspondingly:

```
db = get_db()
db.execute(
   'UPDATE post '
   'SET payment =:payment '
   'WHERE unique_id =:unique_id',
   payment='done', unique_id=1)
)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Is there a way without using SQLAlchemy and using the standard sqlite3 syntax ?

Comment: And by the way there is an extra bracket in your example. Infortunately, I tried your answer without success (I get this error message : "TypeError: execute() takes no keyword arguments"). Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This should as expected:

```
  payment = 'done'
  unique_id = 1
  db = get_db()
  db.execute("UPDATE posts SET payment = %s WHERE unique_id = %s;", \
             (payment, unique_id,))  
  db.commit()
```